# Integrating a payment gateway with Django-Oscar?

Tags: django, django-oscar

I want to integrate a payment gateway with oscar. I have integrated [oscar-paypal](https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar-paypal) it works fine. Should I follow oscar-paypal and try to emulate it ? 
[This document](http://django-oscar.readthedocs.org/en/latest/howto/how_to_integrate_payment.html)  doesn't gives the starting information but not exactly ?

I need this. To create order, change basket status, make payments, send email, and many other steps that oscar-paypal is doing.

Comment: what payment gateway you want to integrate

Comment: Ecommerce on Open edX uses Oscar too. Take a look at their payment processor implementation: https://github.com/edx/ecommerce/tree/master/ecommerce/extensions/payment/processors you might benefit from it.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use payu which is also very easyily available and can be customized. 
`pip install git+https://github.com/SalahAdDin/django-oscar-payu#egg=payu` 
this would clone the payu application which has similar implementation as oscar-paypal. then edit the views.py in the nonseamless navigate to through the code and change the `self.sessions.['currency']` to the currency which u want to use but the default currency it works with is INR. Then your payment_detail.html just replicate what you have as in paypal and change the paypal url to payu. Just switch paypal to payu. That is all.

credit to https://github.com/SalahAdDin/

Answer (score 0):

Following the steps of Oscar Paypal is a pretty good idea. It's a pretty well written project. There  are [facades](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern) written that abstract the details of communicating with the Paypal [Express](https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar-paypal/blob/master/paypal/express/facade.py) and [PayFlow](https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar-paypal/blob/master/paypal/payflow/facade.py) APIs. The facade functions are then called from the `views.py` in each package, which is where the real integration with Oscar begins.

The Paypal Express implementation for example is integrated with Oscar pretty much by subclassing the [PaymentDetailsView](https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar-paypal/blob/master/paypal/express/views.py#L170) class and calling the necessary functions implemented in the `paypal.express.facade` package. There is also a [ShippingOptionsView](https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar-paypal/blob/master/paypal/express/views.py#L392) that provides some linkage with Paypal shipping.

Comment: how do I integrate a  payment gateway like paystack. here is the link to django-paystack. https://github.com/gbozee/django-paystack