# Integration of Stripe in Django Oscar

Tags: django, docker, stripe-payments

i'm following following instructions for the integration of stripe in django oscar:
https://github.com/sayonetech/django-oscar-stripe

I don't get the last point:

> Include the urls mentioned in the dashboard into the projects root urls.

What for urls are meant here? I only find my stripe.api_key but no url on the stripe dashboard.

Thank you in advance,
molm

Comment: this project is a year old with no documentation whatsoever. I dont think you should trust it.

Comment: Do you know an alternative to integrate stripe in oscar?

Comment: [Django Packages - Stripe](https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/stripe/)

Comment: you can take a look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51243465/how-to-integrate-stripe-payments-gateway-with-django-oscar). Hope this helps:)