# How to integrate stripe 3D secure payments, with Strong Customer Authentication (SCA) in django-oscar?

Tags: django, django-oscar, stripe-payments

I have followed [these steps](https://groups.google.com/g/django-oscar/c/Cr8sBI0GBu0/m/dbNnT1SoBQAJ) as mentioned here for setting up stripe in Django-oscar, in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51243465/how-to-integrate-stripe-payments-gateway-with-django-oscar)

I have integrated everything and the payment and checkout functionality is working.
I assume the above code is using the *"Stripe Charge API"* as a Stripe Payment Option
to accept one-time payments with Stripe. (I am not sure, correct me if I am wrong).

Now I want to integrate the 3D secure, Stripe integration due to Strong Customer Authentication (SCA).

for integrating the SCA, I checked that I will have to use *"Payment Intents API"* which supports SCA.
I have a few questions here:

1. Do I need to remove the existing flow and use the "Payment Intents API" instead?
2. If yes, the  3d secure, banks interface which appears before the final checkout page,
   will appear after 3rd step(Payment) in Django-oscar or after 4th step(Preview) in django-oscar ?
3. Most importantly, how can I integrate 3D secure in this existing checkout flow that I currently have.
   I also have dj-stripe installed in my application. Please suggest me the steps and approach I need to follow step by step.

Please, point me in the right direction, I just shared my understanding, I need to integrate 3D secure in Django-oscar, in the current flow.

I can also attach the handle_payment() method code and anything that is required for you to check. Just let me know what is required.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any *answer* with code at the link, but in the *question* the user is implementing the "Charges" API which is not SCA-compliant.

If you have a working payment flow using Charges for one-time payments, you should [review the guide to work through your integration updates](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-intents/migration) to use Payment Intents, or [find the applicable guide for other scenarios](https://stripe.com/docs/strong-customer-authentication/migration).

Broadly speaking, the core support for 3DSv2 is handle when you "confirm" the payment using Stripe.js with [`confirmCardPayment`](https://stripe.com/docs/js/payment_intents/confirm_card_payment) (in step 2 of the guide linked above) which will handle the 3DS authentication for you.

Comment: I have checked the links, however, I want to understand it in terms of django-oscar, could you please guide the steps that need to be followed in the existing code of that link (I have updated the link. Please check now)

Comment: I don't know anything about django-oscar, so I can't really say and I'm not sure you'll find any step by step guide for _exactly_ your scenario. You'll need to work through the general integration guides for python and apply as appropriate for django-oscar. If you have more specific questions about challenges in _particular steps_ or _errors encountered_ I'd encourage you to post them.

Comment: I'd suggest reviewing the integration guide for SCA-compliant payments here, and selecting the python snippets: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment This should give you a good idea of the pieces involved in the final result that you will be migrating your integration towards.

Comment: As you mentioned i am using the charges API currently, so do I have to change the whole flow of handling payment now? 
If yes, then do I need to integrate "stripe checkout and "payment intent API" both for implementing SCA. ?

Comment: or does "stripe checkout" automatically handles the "3D secure SCA" ? as mentioned here from the docs :
"Accept card payments with the Payment Intents API and Stripe’s new version of Checkout—a prebuilt, Stripe-hosted checkout flow that automatically handles SCA requirements for you. Checkout is customizable and lets you accept payments for one-time purchases and subscriptions on your website."

Comment: Using Checkout ( https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout ) fully support SCA and is definitely less work to integrate. In fact, Integration Builder was just recently updated to add a guided flow for setting up Checkout: https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/integration-builder

Comment: I have checked the checkout and i understood it, but I have a question that when do we use "Payment Intent API", is there any requirement of using it in my case?

Comment: Can I also use Checkout in case of recurring payments or is Checkout for one time payments only?

Comment: I need to use Stripe Checkout with stripe connect, as I have a saas based application, where there are multiple merchants who have different stripe keys.